# How to access a plugin in a maven child module from the parent module

Tags: maven, fabric8-maven-plugin

I have a maven multi-module setup, which includes the fabric8 plugin in a profile defined in a child module to build a Docker image if the profile is active, see below

Root pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>control</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>parent</module>
        <module>docker</module>
        <module>...</module>
        <module>...</module>
        <module>...</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Child pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>Docker</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.34.1</version>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
                                <version>${aws.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <configuration>
                            <registry>${aws.ecr.registry}</registry>
                            <images>
                                <image>
                                    <name>${aws.ecr.registry}/${aws.ecr.repository}:${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>
                                    <build>
                                        <contextDir>${project.build.directory}/docker.tmp/</contextDir>
                                    </build>
                                </image>
                            </images>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>docker-build</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>docker-push</id>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>push</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Runing a normal build, i.e. `mvn clean install -PDocker` completes successfully, but if I call one of the docker goals from the parent module directly, e.g. `mvn -PDocker docker:help` it fails with this error

```
No plugin found for prefix 'docker' in the current project and in the plugin groups
```

Running the same command from the docker directory completes successfully.

What changes are needed so the command completes successfully in the root directory?

Comment: You can use below commands from your parent pom level 
`mvn -pl <name_of_child_module_containing_dockerfile> docker:build` to build the docker image and `mvn -pl <name_of_child_module_containing_dockerfile> docker:push` to push it.

Since your chils pom contains `<artifactId>docker</artifactId>`  , so from your parent pom level you can run `mvn -pl docker docker:build` and `mvn -pl docker docker:push`